# Is there a way to find md5sum for Google drive uploads?

Tags: google-drive-api, md5sum

I have to upload some large files and folders to Google Drive. In order to make sure data is uploaded perfectly, I need to check their md5sums. Is there any other way to check uploaded files are completely uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

When you upload the file the file resource is returned to you.  The [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) contains a md5Checksum you should just be able to compare it with the one you have.

Try a file.list and you can see them all.

```
let files = Drive.Files.list();
for (item of files.items) {
    Logger.log(item['md5Checksum']);
}
```